# Submit app through different developer

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am in the finishing stages of my first app! And i encountered a problem that a few months ago i didn't foresee. I used my friend's app developer account to get started with xcode and never signed up for my own, but i dont want his account to be tangled with all the application updates and what not. So basically, my question is: Is there any easy way to transfer the application from one apple developer account to another? Thanks in advance for any advice/answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official answer is No. From the iTunes Connect FAQ:

Apple currently don't offer any way to transfer individual applications from one developer account to another.

Comment: Is it possible to drag all the old files into a new project with a different account linked to it? because thats what im planning on doing in a few days.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. The only way is to submit your app using a different bundle identifier because iTunes won't let you use the bundle identifier of an existing app.